# Plotting graph of an implicit function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, graph, matlab-figure, symbolic-math

I am unsure about how to do a plot (graph) of an implicit function in MATLAB. Let us say a have a two-variable polynomial `P` and an implicit function (not solvable explicitly) `P(x,y)=0`. How do I plot the latter graph in the x-y coordinate system (with a grid)?

I tried to use the contour on `z=P(x,y)`, but it gives me level curves at several levels that MATLAB chooses. I wont just the one level at `z=0`.

Comment: `ezplot` is your friend, or `fsurf` probably (or any of the `f____` family of functions)

Comment: Say we have $P(x,y)=x^3y+3y^2x^2-5y^3+xy+1=0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily, MATLAB contains implicit function plotting and the command is fimplicit, with appropriate option for specifying intervals for the variables etc. So, if we want to plot the implicit graph of P(x,y)=0, the way to do it is as follows (this is over ML favorite interval [-5 5]x[-5 5], there is an option for specifying other rectangles...):

P=@(x,y) P(x,y);

fimplicit(P)

grid

This will plot the graph of P(x,y)=0 with a grid. Very easy and elegant.

Answer (score 2):

The entire suit of `f___` where `____` is a plotting function is what you want.

For example.

```
syms x
syms y
fsurf(x^3*y+3*y^2*x^2-5*y^3+x*y+1)
```

Comment: Well, sure it gives me the surface z=P(x,y). But I want the graph of the curve(s) x^3y+3y^2x^2-5y^3+xy+1=0

Comment: In other words, this does not answer my question, but gives one of the many ways to plot a 3D graph. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Rado yes, you are missing reading through the list of `f_____` functions to find the one you want more. e.g. maybe its `fimplicit`

Comment: Thanks Ander. I did not find your fsurf comment useful so I went into the obvious mode of looking for implicit plotting. That I did not look for implicit function plotting in ML help menu in the first place is due to the fact that I had a prejudice that ML would not have it. I am happy I found it. I now see that you have eventually given me the answer I was looking for.  Thanks for your help.